# Microsoft Edge Developer Tools for Visual Studio Code doesn't auto attach debugger to Angular project

Tags: angular, visual-studio-code, vscode-debugger

I'm having some issues getting the "[auto attach debugger](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-edge-devtools#attaching-automatically-when-launching-the-browser-for-debugging)" feature of [Microsoft Edge Developer Tools for Visual Studio Code](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools) to work.

I generated a fresh angular project (`ng new`) and added this launch.json config

```
{
  "configurations": [
    // this one works. It opens a chrome window and hits my break points.
    {
      "type": "pwa-chrome", // this is not "Microsoft Edge Developer Tools for Visual Studio Code"
      "name": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "request": "launch",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/"
    },
    // this one does not work. It opens a headless edge window, but it does not hit my break points.
    {
      "type": "vscode-edge-devtools.debug", // this is "Microsoft Edge Developer Tools for Visual Studio Code"
      "request": "launch",
      "name": "Launch Microsoft Edge and open the Edge DevTools",
      "url": "http://localhost:4200/",
      "webRoot": "${workspaceFolder}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have these extension settings

```json
{
  "vscode-edge-devtools.enableNetwork": true,
  "vscode-edge-devtools.headless": true,
  "vscode-edge-devtools.defaultUrl": "http://localhost:4200/"
}
```

[image]

I tried fiddling around with `sourceMapPathOverrides` but I can't seem to get it right.

The `webpack:///` content looks like this

[image]

- VSCode Version: 1.53.2 (system setup)
- Microsoft Edge Version: 88.0.705.68 (Official build) (64-bit)
- Microsoft Edge Tools for VS Code (ms-edgedevtools.vscode-edge-devtools) Version: 1.1.3
- Debugger for Microsoft Edge (msjsdiag.debugger-for-edge) Version: 1.0.15

Comment: I'm also very interested in this. Debugging and using Angular DevTools at the same time in the same browser tab seems to be not very straightforward.

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue. My problem was that I did not have `sourceMap` explicitly enabled in my `tsconfig.json` file:

```
{
    "compileOnSave": false,
    "compilerOptions": {
     ///....
        "sourceMap": true
    }
}
```

I also had to enable it in my `angular.json` file like this:

```
"architect": {
                "build": {
                    "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
                    "options": {
                        ///...
                        "hmr": {
                            "sourceMap": true, <= for me since I'm using hmr here
                            "fileReplacements": [
                                {
                                    "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                                    "with": "src/environments/environment.hmr.ts"
                                }
                            ]
                        },
                        "development": {
                            "sourceMap": true <= and here
                        }
                    }
                },
```